# What's with the Facebook malware which posts obscene posts in all the groups?

Tags: malware, virus, facebook

How to get rid of the Facebook malware which sends pornographic posts in all the groups you belong to? I always made fun of people who became victim of this malware/virus saying they are not cautious enough, but today morning, I woke up and find I have posted obscene posts in all the groups.
I removed a few apps, which I thought were suspicious and I also checked the browser extension along with recently installed programs, but I couldn't find anything and in the end, so I had to deactivate my Facebook. This was one of the most embarrassing days. I never thought I could become a victim being so cautious while browsing the Internet.

Comment: +1 for giving me a feeling of Schadenfreude. Could it be possible that your facebook password got leaked?

Comment: Questions about how to remove malware from your machine are off topic here.

Comment: @schroeder That's why i added a PS. Although, i wanted to know more about malware rather than just removing them because i removed all the browsers, and made Linux my primary OS which was secondary and that did help. It was most probably  a chrome plugin which i don't recall installing. I thought that i'd gain some knowledge about this threat and make others aware who are less knowledgeable. I appreciate the help i got here.

Answer (score 5):

Go through the apps you gave some permission on facebook. Especially the "post on my behalf" permission. Remove any you don't trust (or don't remember giving them permissions).

Anyway, it might be a one time thing, and there is nothing to get rid of. Read through [this blog post](https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/06/analyzing-a-facebook-clickbait-worm.html) for more information.

In the extreme case, you might be indeed infected by malware (I don't think so in case you were really cautios and don't remember running any executables). However, if this is the case I recommend scanning your PC for malware (there are various forums out there where you can get help with this).

Comment: I wanted to upvote you (for the first part) but I can not because what you mentioned in the second part is incorrect: if your machine is infected, it won't infect your Facebook, Gmail, Twitter ... accounts. Regards

Comment: Yes, I never installed such apps on first place except a game(Marvel avengers alliance) and apps like Instagram, Interview Street etc. I checked my apps because those are the basic things but i couldn't find anything, although there were some old apps which i don't really use so i removed them as well. The link you gave mentions something about close button of a pop-up, that might be the reason and it might have got executed in background. I will give my system a restore for 2 days range and reinstall the browsers again to see if it works.

Comment: @begueradj I tended to think exact the same way. Anyway, after a few articles like this http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2015/Jan/131 I chose to mention it in the answer. However, I had no chance to test the mentioned executable (or any similiar) by myself, yet. Therefor, probably I shouldn't have include it as I'm not 100% sure it is posibble.

Comment: @begueradj Go ahead and explain me how a malware that has full access to a PC cannot post something on your behalf on Facebook. Yes, the "second part" of his answer is less likely than the "first part" but it still is a plausible scenario.

Comment: @begueradj Given browsers cache sessions and often even passwords it is entirely possibly sufficiently cunning malware could extract the users Facebook password or session cookies and either distribute them or use them to make posts etc.

Comment: Thank you. It was a chrome plugin i guess which i don't know how installed itself. I removed all the browsers, cleared the data related to them. Made Linux as my primary OS and installed aviator. It looks fine as for now. I can help others with this now because i see tons of people falling for this every day on Facebook.